# How can i get roles of users in sharepoint 2010 using Client Object Model?

Tags: roles

I need to get roles for current user(like visitors,contributors,administrators etc.) from sharepoint 2010. I am using Silverlight client object model to deal with sharepoint 2010 API.

Kindly share your knowledge.

thanks & regards

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code to get the groups in Silverlight app by calling the GetGroupCollectionFromUserAsync method of UserGroup.asmx web service.

http://www.innovawiz.com/get-the-sharepoint-groups-a-user-is-part-of-using-sharepoint-object-model

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you explore possibilities of SharePoint Web services? I think you can reach your goal much easier by using web services then by using Client Object Model.

Take a look at [UserGroup Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.aspx) and its method [UserGroup.GetRoleCollectionFromUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.getrolecollectionfromuser.aspx). I believe this method to be exactly what are you looking for.

Here you can find one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213459/determining-users-role-in-a-sharepoint-site-workspace-using-the-webservices-api

And here is explanation how to consume SharePoint Web Services from Silverlight:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/04/28/sharepoint-for-developers-part-4-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-from-silverlight.aspx

Comment: Thanks vedran, i just came back here . i achieved user permission level with the help of RoleAssignmentCollection, RoleDefinitionCollection.